# How to create nodes with variable labels in cypher?

Tags: json, variables, neo4j, label, cypher

I am using JSON APOC plugin to create nodes from a JSON with lists in it, and I am trying to create nodes whose label is listed as an element in the list:

```
{
    "pdf":[
        {
            "docID": "docid1", 
            "docLink": "/examplelink.pdf", 
            "docType": "PDF"
        }
],
    "jpeg":[
        {
            "docID": "docid20", 
            "docLink": "/examplelink20.pdf", 
            "docType": "JPEG"
        }
],
...,}
```

And I want to both iterate through the doctypes (pdf, jpeg) and set the label as the docType property in the list. Right now I have to do separate blocks for each doctype list (jpeg: [], pdf:[]):

```
WITH "file:////input.json" AS url
CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value
UNWIND value.pdf as doc
MERGE (d:PDF {docID: doc.docID})
```

I'd like to loop through the doctype lists, creating the node for each doctype with the label as either the list name (pdf) or the node's docType name (PDF). Something like:

```
WITH "file:////input.json" AS url
CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value
for each doctypelist in value
for each doc in doctype list
MERGE(d:doc.docType {docID: doc.docID})
```

Or

```
WITH "file:////input.json" AS url
CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value
for each doctypelist in value
for each doc in doctype list
MERGE(d {docID: doc.docID})
ON CREATE SET d :doc.docType
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cypher currently does not support this. To set a label, you must hardcode it into the Cypher. You could do filters, or multiple matches to do this in a tedious way, but if you aren't allowed to install any plug-ins to your Neo4j db, I would recommend either just putting an index on the type, or use a node+relation instead of the label. (There are a lot of valid doc types, so if you have to support them all, pure Cypher will make it very painful.)

Using APOC however, there is a [procedure](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_using_cypher_and_apoc_to_move_a_property_value_to_a_label) specifically for this `apoc.create.addLabels`

```
CREATE (:Movie {title: 'A Few Good Men', genre: 'Drama'});
MATCH (n:Movie)
CALL apoc.create.addLabels( id(n), [ n.genre ] ) YIELD node
REMOVE node.genre
RETURN node;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this to get the node label from dataframe:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    label = row.label # for node label
    records, summary, keys=  driver.execute_query(
    "create (c:"""+ label + """ {name :$cname})",
    cname=row.Name,
    database_="neo4j",)
```