# How to create nodes with parameterized labels in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

It has been a while (2 years) since that same question was asked. Back then, creating nodes or relationships with parameterized labels was not supported in Cypher. Is it better supported today?

What I want to accomplish is to simply to create nodes in Neo4J using Cypher, from a CSV file, providing that the file contains 2 columns, one for node type and one for node name:

```
  LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://xyz/nodes.csv' AS line
  WITH line.type as label
  CREATE (:EVAL(label) { name: line.name })
```

Here is the [link to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52706569/how-to-create-nodes-with-variable-labels-in-cypher), asked 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure Cypher you can't, but nowadays everybody use the [APOC library](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-apoc/) with the [`apoc.create.node`](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.create/apoc.create.node/) procedure :

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://xyz/nodes.csv' AS line
CALL apoc.create.node(['EVAL', line.type], {name: line.name})
YIELD node
RETURN node
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Notice that in the browser, I've got the error 
"Query cannot conclude with CALL (must be RETURN or an update clause)", that I overcame by appending
YIELD node WITH node RETURN node

Comment: correct, forgot to add it, will add to the answer, it will not be only in the browser